# Отключить проверки на ошибки при компиляции классов

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Как можно отключить проверки на ошибки когда IDEA компилирует проект, по картинке ниже видно что выводятся Warnings, мне бы не то что не хотелось получать, а просто чтобы он не тратил на это время без вмешательства в код, проект большой и так занимает много времени
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ошибки, а предупреждения. Предупреждения можно "вырубать" аннотацией [SuppressWarning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html), в данном случае надо ставить аннотацию перед методом/классом, который ее генерирует:

```
@SuppressWarning("cast")
public void myMethod() {
}
```

Comment: Возможно ли отключить это без вмешательства в код? Дело даже не в предупреждениях а в том что он тратит на это время, вот бы проверял бы только ошибки компиляции

Comment: Опция компилятора `-nowarn`, но не советую этого делать. Выглядит как езда на машине, в котором вырублена приборная панель :)